# How to create a database automatically with Dropwizard

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, dropwizard

I'm looking for a way I can check and create a PostgreSQL database if it does not exist when my Dropwizard app starts up. I am working with multiple databases and so we've chosen to load all of our connections and persistence units with private modules. I've looked at using JDBI but that appears to break the approach we want to take with the private modules. I've also read up on using Dropwizard Migrations but that appears to be pretty xml heavy which is what I want to avoid.

If I start with a blank database already made Hibernate will create my schema just fine so the only part I'm missing is having the database get created automatically if it does not exist.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have at least one connection that is static I believe. E.g. if your databases are:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/X
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Y
```

Then you will have to have a connection to

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
```

In your startup code, you will need to check manually if all databases exist, then create them if they don't. After that you can load the rest of your persistence contexts.

For example, a quick snippet on how to do this with pure jdbc

```
public class DBTest {

public static DataSource datasource() { 
    MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?"
              + "user=root");
    return ds;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    DataSource datasource = datasource();
    ResultSet executeQuery = datasource.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("Show databases;");

    List<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();

    while(executeQuery.next()) {

        tables.add(executeQuery.getString(1));
    }

    if(!tables.contains("MyNewDB")) {
        datasource.getConnection().createStatement().execute("Create database MyNewDB;");
    }

}
```

}

EDIT:

As correctly pointed out, the above is a mysql solution. I installed postgres and did a quick adaption, so this works for me with postgres. Main problem was, that there is no "show databases" for postgres. Replacing that (and the connection etc) fixes that. Works fairly the same:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection connection = null;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/","artur", "");


        ResultSet executeQuery = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT datname FROM pg_database;");

        List<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();

        while(executeQuery.next()) {

            tables.add(executeQuery.getString(1));
        }



        if(!tables.contains("MyNewDB")) {
            connection.createStatement().execute("Create database MyNewDB;");
        }
        connection.close();

    }
```

Note also, that the jdbc part (handling connection etc) should  be handled properly. It gives the right idea I hope :)

Comment: Can you be more specific? I didn't have postgres installed and assumed that from an sql point of view it should be fairly the same.

Comment: Right :) I wrote up the postgres version of the same code.